# Difficulties setting up overlapped serial port communication

Tags: c++, serial-port, readfile

I am struggling to communicate with a device via serial COM port.

At first I managed to READ and WRITE to the port with a fairly simple non-overlapped setup. But now I've realized that I have a delay between the WRITE and the READ functions of about 100ms.

**Problem:** I need to check for an answer after about 15ms in order to reply immediately.

I have no clue how to achieve this, so I tried to set up an overlapped communication and came across this Microsoft Documentation: [Serial Communications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx)

Now I cant even get the READ part to work.

Here is my code for now

```
int main() {
    LPCWSTR port = L"COM3:";

    HANDLE hComm = CreateFile(port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);
    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) cout << "ERROR " << GetLastError() << endl;
    else {
        DWORD dwRead;
        DWORD dwRes;
        BOOL fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
        OVERLAPPED osReader = { 0 };

        //Create overlapped event
        osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
        if (osReader.hEvent == NULL) cout << "ERROR " << GetLastError() << endl;
        else {
            BYTE Byte[2];
            while (true) {
                if (!fWaitingOnRead) {
                    //Issue read operation
                    if (!ReadFile(hComm, &Byte, sizeof(Byte), &dwRead, &osReader)); cout << "ERROR " << GetLastError() << endl;
                    else {
                        cout << std::hex << (int)Byte[0] << " " << std::hex << (int)Byte[1] << endl;
                        fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(osReader.hEvent, 500);
                    switch (dwRes) {
                        // Read completed.
                        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                            if (!GetOverlappedResult(hComm, &osReader, &dwRead, FALSE)) cout << "ERROR " << GetLastError() << endl;
                            else {
                                cout << std::hex << (int)Byte[0] << " " << std::hex << (int)Byte[1] << endl;
                            }

                            //  Reset flag so that another opertion can be issued.
                            fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This Code should output the Results of the READ function to the console. But it fails everytime and GetLastError() gives me **997**

I hope somebody can point out my mistakes, or give me a hint how to work around this overlapped construction which I don't quiet understand yet.

Comment: By design, 997 == "Overlapped I/O operation is in progress".  That means it worked.  There is no point in using overlapped I/O if you next going to wait for it to complete.  If you are doing this to get the 500 msec timeout then use SetCommTimeouts().

Comment: It's difficult to understand, much less solve, a problem that's poorly stated.  *"I need to check for an answer after about 15ms in order to reply immediately."* -- 15ms relative to what?  *"Reply"* to an *"answer"* sounds illogical. *"... I have a delay between the WRITE and the READ functions of about 100ms."* -- How did you measure this, and what do you think you measured?  Beware that the actual I/O (at the hardware level) is not necessarily synchronous with the syscalls in your code (e.g. a write request could return *before* the last byte of the message was actually transmitted).